# Spring MVC project update by maven

Tags: maven, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee

I have just created an application using Spring MVC.
But when I update this project using maven I get the following error:

> An internal error occurred during: "Updating Maven Project".
>   org.eclipse.m2e.wtp.WTPProjectsUtil.isM2eWtpDisabled(Lorg/eclipse/m2e/core/project/IMavenProjectFacade;Lorg/eclipse/core/runtime/IProgressMonitor;)Z

Here is an image to help you understand better:

[image: Maven update]

And here are the project properties:

[image: project properties]

How can I deal with this error ?